# Import appdirs error while deploying app trough heroku

Tags: python, windows, heroku, deployment, setuptools

```
remote:          Installing build dependencies: started
remote:          Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: started
remote:          Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
remote:        ERROR: Exception:
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
remote:            status = run_func(*args)
remote:                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 245, in wrapper
remote:            return func(self, options, args)
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 377, in run
remote:            requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
remote:                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 95, in resolve
remote:            result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
remote:                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 546, in resolve
remote:            state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
remote:                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 397, in resolve
remote:            self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
remote:            if not criterion.candidates:
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/structs.py", line 156, in __bool__
remote:            return bool(self._sequence)
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
remote:            return any(self)
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
remote:            return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
remote:            candidate = func()
remote:                        ^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 182, in _make_candidate_from_link
remote:            base: Optional[BaseCandidate] = self._make_base_candidate_from_link(
remote:                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/factory.py", line 228, in _make_base_candidate_from_link
remote:            self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
remote:                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 293, in __init__
remote:            super().__init__(
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
remote:            self.dist = self._prepare()
remote:                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
remote:            dist = self._prepare_distribution()
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/candidates.py", line 304, in _prepare_distribution
remote:            return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 525, in prepare_linked_requirement
remote:            return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 640, in _prepare_linked_requirement
remote:            dist = _get_prepared_distribution(
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 71, in _get_prepared_distribution
remote:            abstract_dist.prepare_distribution_metadata(
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 54, in prepare_distribution_metadata
remote:            self._install_build_reqs(finder)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 124, in _install_build_reqs
remote:            build_reqs = self._get_build_requires_wheel()
remote:                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/sdist.py", line 101, in _get_build_requires_wheel
remote:            return backend.get_requires_for_build_wheel()
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 751, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
remote:            return super().get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings=cs)
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 166, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
remote:            return self._call_hook('get_requires_for_build_wheel', {
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_impl.py", line 321, in _call_hook
remote:            raise BackendUnavailable(data.get('traceback', ''))
remote:        pip._vendor.pyproject_hooks._impl.BackendUnavailable: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
remote:            obj = import_module(mod_path)
remote:                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1310, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-swc9jzl2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
remote:            import setuptools.version
remote:          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-swc9jzl2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
remote:            import pkg_resources
remote:          File "/tmp/pip-build-env-swc9jzl2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
remote:            from pkg_resources.extern import appdirs
remote:        ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs' from 'pkg_resources.extern' (/tmp/pip-build-env-swc9jzl2/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py)
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to voiceassistant.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/voiceassistant.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/voiceassistant.git'
E:\final project\streamlit\>
```

My `requirements.txt` contains:

```
streamlit==1.4.0
sounddevice==0.4.2
pyttsx3==2.90
speechrecognition==3.8.1
scipy<1.7.3
streamlit-webrtc==0.21.0
pyaudio==0.2.11; sys_platform == 'win32'
appdirs==1.4.4
setuptools==60.9.0
```

I added `appdirs` and `setuptools` by suggestion of ChatGPT but it didn't solve the issue. I am on Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: "by suggestion of gpt"—ChatGPT is _not intelligent_. It just spits out words that kind of go together, but it doesn't understand what it's saying. Don't trust it.

Comment: Instead of manually mangling all of that output, just paste it then select it and click the code block button. I tried to fix your code blocks but they still have a bunch of extraneous backslashes in them... You don't need to (shouldn't) add blank lines between each line, and you don't need to (shouldn't) try to escape anything. (And you _never_ need to escape square brackets in Markdown. They don't do anything.)

Comment: Side note: instead of using `appdirs` which has not been updated in 4 years, I recommend using  [`platformdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) which has the same features but is being kept up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Setuptools v60.9.0 uses a custom [`MetaPathFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-meta-path-finder) hook that allows importing [`appdirs`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v60.9.0/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py#L73) from the [pkg_resources/_vendor/appdirs.py](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v60.9.0/pkg_resources/_vendor/appdirs.py) file. All these files are in place, so the error is a bit puzzling.

I have a couple of hypothesis about this problem:

- There seems to be something wrong with the installation of `setuptools` and/or a leak in the ["build isolation"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/build-system/pyproject-toml/#build-isolation) provided by `pip`[^1].

  This would mean that while the code you are trying to import uses some files from version `60.9.0`, somehow the import machinery is trying to get `setuptools.extern` from a different version of setuptools (`appdirs` got replaced by `platformdirs` in `66.0.0`).
- There is another `MetaPathFinder` higher up in the `sys.meta_path` precedence interfering with `pkg_resources.extern`.

My suggestion is to incrementally try the following:

- Update the installation of `pip` before attempting any other installation.
- Update the version of `setuptools` in your `requiremetns.txt`.
- Update the lower boundary of the version of `setuptools` in `pyproject.toml` (if you have one).

[^1]: Old versions of `pip` would have problems with build isolation leaks for certain systems. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11430, https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11053#issuecomment-1104681280, https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6264.